# selecting header with if statements

Tags: php, forms, header, download

Im trying to make a download page like this:

```
<?php
$filetype = $_POST['filetype'];

echo "$filetype";

if( $filetype == '256mp3'){
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=mp3.html');
    header('Content-type: text/html');
    readfile('mp3.html');
}
if($filetype == 'apple lossless' ){
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=applelossless.html');
    header('Content-type: text/html');
    readfile('applelossless.html');
}
?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I use a form to post the variable $filetype, which then selects the file i want to be downloaded.

I am getting this error

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/thetempers/www/presskit/download.php:5) in /home/thetempers/www/presskit/download.php on line 13

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/thetempers/www/presskit/download.php:5) in /home/thetempers/www/presskit/download.php on line 14
```

why is this not working there are no spaces before the  tags

Answer (score 2):

Because you have `echo $filetype` before your header statement. You can't output anything if you intend to set the header. If you really must, then try looking at [ob_start](http://php.net/ob_start).

Also, I don't get what you want to achieve, earlier you've already outputs the html using `readfile()`, but later you are outputting another `<html>`, is that intended?

Answer (score 1):

remove this

echo "$filetype";

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 potential issues I see with your code:

- the line `echo "$filetype";` writes data to the client causing headers to be sent and then subsequent calls to `header()` fail.
- you may need a call to `exit;` right after each call to `readfile()` (assuming `readfile()` doesn't end with `exit;`) in order to prevent the html below the `if()` conditions from being sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Oh man I feel pretty dim now lol.

this works.

Thanks guys!

```
if( $filetype == '256mp3'){
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=mp3.html');
    header('Content-type: text/html');
    readfile('mp3.html');
}
if($filetype == 'apple lossless' ){
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=applelossless.html');
    header('Content-type: text/html');
    readfile('applelossless.html');
}
?>
```

Comment: Please mark one of the other answers as correct by clicking the checkbox next to it on the left. Then delete this answer.